# jquery ajax request with semicolons in query string?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to submit an ajax request in jQuery with semicolon separator instead of ampersand separator for query string?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.some.host/event",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    foo: "cat",
    bar: "dog"
}});
```

yields

```
http://api.some.host/event?foo=cat&bar=dog
```

and what i want is

```
http://api.some.host/event?foo=cat;bar=dog
```

Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Why would you want such a thing?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Putting them directly into the URL should do it. Good luck dealing with it on the other end though.

Comment: Do you know that `foo=cat&bar=dog` is one of the default encodings that probably every server understands?

Comment: [http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2](Ampersands in URI Attribute Values) - On the server side it's dealt with already. Anyway, I'm just asking if there is some parameter I can set in my ajax request to use semicolons instead of ampersands.

Comment: No one uses it that way, the W3C is stupid.  They're citing it as a convenience, but when we developers do things for convenience, it's called a HACK.  Just use ampersands on both ends of your implementation, the internet will thank you.

Comment: The W3C recommendation from 1999 always intended the ampersand to be the primary delimiter, and the semicolon a secondary alternatives for those too lazy to escape their XML variables. Furthermore, as of 2014 it is now obsolete; in the HTML5 spec W3C states that parameters must [be the result of strictly splitting the string payload on U+0026 AMPERSAND characters (&)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.some.host/event?foo=cat;bar=dog",
  type: "GET"
}).done(function() {
  // do something
});
```

You can build up the url with string concatenation. There is no jquery provided way to do it with the `;` seperator.

Comment: Except that the link you included includes the text: "This convention is a W3C recommendation.[5] W3C recommends that all web servers support semicolon separators in addition to ampersand separators[6] to allow application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings in URLs within HTML documents without having to entity escape ampersands." And in my case, the semicolon is being handled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid question, and in my opinion an important issue jQuery needs to address - not sure why you're getting so much pushback in this thread.  Nginx and Apache both have easy ways to change the separator to ';' along with most web frameworks, so it is entirely up to front-end developers to make this change happen at this point.  Until then, this is the best way to change the call in jQuery in my opinion:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.some.host/event",
  type: "GET",
  data:
    "foo=cat;"+
    "bar=dog;"
  ,
  processData: false
});
```

Ideally, jQuery would add an additional flag in the ajax api that allows you to set dataSeparator to ';', but alas.

People are wrong when they say `?foo=cat;bar=dog` is not a valid query string.

Comment: There is no good argument for allowing semicolons instead of ampersands at this point, period.  No one expects it, and almost everyone will be confused by it.  Can you give me a name of ONE widely-adopted service that does this?

Comment: Just about every ad server on the planet does it that way (like DFA if you want a specific example).  Look at the network traffic on this page for another example - pixel.quantserve.com is using semicolons.  Consumer facing interfaces don't use them, but its more common than you would think behind the scenes.